# How can this client-server communication method save two kernel crossings?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, interrupt

In an OS book, when it talks about client-server communication, it says:

> Client-server communication is a common pattern in many systems, and so one can ask: how can we improve its performance? One step is to recognize that **both the client and the server issue a write immediately followed by a read**, to wait for the other side to reply; at the cost of adding a system call, **these can be combined to eliminate two kernel crossings per round trip**.

I wonder how "**issue a write immediately followed by a read**" can save 2 kernel crossings per round trip.

A `write` issues a system call into the kernel, causes a kernel crossing from user mode to kernel mode. When the `write` finishes, the OS returns to user-code, from kernel mode to user mode.

Then, `read` is called, and causes a kernel crossing from user mode to kernel mode, and then it returns to user-code, from kernel mode to user mode.

So what is the **saved** kernel crossing? Does it mean that the when the `write` finishes, it does not return to user code and user mode, instead, it directly runs `read` in kernel mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as understand the OS book, it is a potential optimization. OS may have a syscall that do write and read at once. It could be a hypothetical syscall like  `int write_read(int fd, char *write_buf, size_t write_len, char *read_buf, size_t *read_len)`. But there is no such call the linux kernel.

Modern kernels do not use interrupts for syscalls so the optimization would not help much. Moreover modern applications that are performance critical usually use some kind of asynchronous, non-blocking handling so the proposed optimization would be useless for them anyway. Further problem with that optimization would be error reporting. If something failed the caller could not easily recognize wheteher read failed or write failed.